# Return values from combining different fields

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, combine, if-statement

I'd like to classify parcels according to combinations of front setbacks and side setbacks. I have a "Fr_sb" field with values 0 (no front setback) and 1 (with front setback), and a "Si_sb" field with values 0 (no side setbacks), 1 (setback on one side of the parcel) and 2 (setbacks on both sides of the parcel). I'd like to combine those values on a third field "Setbs", as follows:

```
if "Fr_sb"=0 and "Si_sb"=0 return "0"
if "Fr_sb"=0 and "Si_sb"=1 return "1"
if "Fr_sb"=0 and "Si_sb"=2 return "2"
if "Fr_sb"=1 and "Si_sb"=0 return "3"
if "Fr_sb"=1 and "Si_sb"=1 return "4"
if "Fr_sb"=1 and "Si_sb"=2 return "5"
```

I'm still learning to code though, and have no idea how to do this using the Field Calculator.

Comment: Hi and welcome to GIS.SE. What software are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Instructions written assuming ArcMap 10.x)

In the Field Calculator window, change your Parser to Python and check Show Codeblock.

You will write a function within the codeblock/"Pre-Logic Script Code" (first box), and then call the function in the block below that, passing in the values of the fields.

This is written as if your `Setbs` field is short integer. If it's string, put quotes around the return value. Also consider: What do you want to happen if none of these are true?  You can add an else statement at the end to handle that case.

```
def setbacks(frontsb, sidesb):
    if frontsb == 0 and sidesb == 0:
        return 0
    elif frontsb == 0 and sidesb == 1:
        return 1
    elif frontsb == 0 and sidesb == 2:
        return 2
    elif frontsb == 1 and sidesb == 0:
        return 3
    elif frontsb == 1 and sidesb == 1:
        return 4
    elif frontsb == 1 and sidesb == 2:
        return 5
```

Then use the function on the field you created like this:

```
Setbs = setbacks(!Fr_sb!, !Si_sb!)
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this can be done much more easily by a python dictionary, e.g.,

`{(0,0):'0', (0,1):'1', (0,2):'2', (1,0):'3', (1,1):'4', (1,2):'5'}.setdefault((!Fr_sb!, !Si_sb!), '999')`

Another advantage of this approach is that it yields '999' if any input value is not a key in the dictionary, which does not throws an exception and also makes easier to filter these records via SQL (i.e., Select by Attribute).